# measure is not viewing the rest data in react-virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

when component did mount the measure is showing some item but when I scrolling the browser the rest of the item is not showing but the measure hight is increasing and the rest of the item is hidden

```
// Default sizes help Masonry decide how many images to batch-measure
  cache:any = new CellMeasurerCache({
    defaultHeight: 250,
    defaultWidth: 200,
    fixedWidth: false,

  });
  // Our masonry layout will use 3 columns with a 10px gutter between
  cellPositioner:any = createMasonryCellPositioner({
    cellMeasurerCache: this.cache,
    columnCount: 6,
    columnWidth: 200,
    spacer: 20,
  });
  cellRenderer = ({index, key, parent, style}:any) => {
    const list:any = this.state.styleFilteration;

    return (
      <CellMeasurer cache={this.cache} index={index} key={key} parent={parent}>

      <this.Text  style={style}  >   
        <this.Image onClick={()=> this.setState({show: true,forDetails: list[index]})}  >
           {list[index].favorite_beers.length == 0 ?
           <this.unFaverit  onClick={(e)=> {e.stopPropagation(); this.fav(list[index].id)}} ><i className="fa fa-heart"></i></this.unFaverit> :
           <this.Faverit onClick={(e)=> {e.stopPropagation(); this.unFav(list[index].id)} } ><i className="fa fa-heart"></i></this.Faverit>}
           </this.Image>
           <this.ImageName >{list[index].title}</this.ImageName>
       </this.Text>

      </CellMeasurer>
    );
  }
```

and my render return

```
<Masonry
   cellCount={this.state.styleFilteration.length}
   cellMeasurerCache={this.cache}
   cellPositioner={this.cellPositioner}
   cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
   height={800}
   width={1300}
   autoHeight
   data={this.state.styleFilteration}

/>
```

Comment: I think `autoHeight` and `data` props on `Masonry` are not needed. Have you tried removing those props? I think `autoHeight` is only needed if you are also using `WindowScroller`.

Comment: if I remove the autoHeight it gives me an error: autoHeight is required